# How to make star ratings stick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented [this star rating snippet](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) with good success in my Chrome extension popup html:

Here is my implementation:

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  color: #e8d04c;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divRating" class="rating">
  <span id="spanRatingExcellent" title="Excellent">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingGood" title="Good">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingFair" title="Fair">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingPoor" title="Poor">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingAwful" title="Awful">☆</span>
</div>
```

It works fine except that this approach doesn't provide a way for the selected star to "stick". For example, if the user clicks 4 stars, when the mouse pointer leaves, I want stars 1-4 to remain highlighted. Instead, all stars unhighlight upon mouseout. But then if the use mouse-overs again and clicks a star, I need correct (original) behavior. And again, if a star is clicked, the selected stars should remain highlighted upon mouse-out and any unselected stars (to the right) would remain unhighlighted.

A pure CSS solution would be cool, but I'm perfectly happy to use jquery or javascript to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spoiler: you'll need javascript to do that, it can't (actually) be implemented in pure CSS.

Comment: @fredrivett just proved me wrong with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989590/3136474) (though I still prefer using JavaScript on that matter).

Comment: All the answers seemed good (thanks all!) but I chose Dinei's because it required the least changes to my existing implementation. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation using pure JavaScript, along with your HTML and CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('divRating').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'span') return;
  
  if (event.target.classList.contains('rated')) {
    event.target.classList.remove('rated');
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('rated'), function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('rated');
    });
    event.target.classList.add('rated');
  }
});
```

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  color: #e8d04c;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before,
.rating > span.rated:before,
.rating > span.rated ~ span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divRating" class="rating">
  <span id="spanRatingExcellent" title="Excellent">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingGood" title="Good">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingFair" title="Fair">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingPoor" title="Poor">☆</span>
  <span id="spanRatingAwful" title="Awful">☆</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure CSS version, then Lea Verou provides that, and is linked to from the article above under the section [Actual Usage](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/#article-header-id-0).

It works by using radio buttons to hold the value of which stars have been selected.

[See the JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/CGP87/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=CGP87) and the [explainer here.](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/)

Here's her code pulled out (not taking credit for this solution, just pointing to it).

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.rating {
    float:left;
}

/* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
   follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
   it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> use [Rate Yo](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) jQuery star rating plugin with data attribute

```js
$(function () {
  $(".rateyo").rateYo().on("rateyo.change", function (e, data) {
    var rating = data.rating;
    $(this).parent().find('.result').text('rating :'+ rating);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="rateyo" data-rateyo-rating="2.5" data-rateyo-num-stars="5"></div>
    <span class='result'>0</span>
</div>
```